# This Linear Layout isn't working as expected

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a fragment, inside I'd like to show an image, and below the image I have 2 Linear Layouts, both start invisible and the needed one will be made visible in the Java code.

The problem is that one of the 2 Linear Layouts is starting within the top LL even though I have specified `android:layout_below="@id/Linear1"`

So:

1. Relative Layout (Outer)
2. Linear (for the image) - > `@id/Linear1`
3. Linear fsView below Linear1 (works fine)
4. Linear doView below Linear1 (starts inside of Linear1 instead of below)

How do I make doView start below Linear1 just like fsView?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="Fragment4">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Linear1"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:src="@drawable/reddit"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fsView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_below="@id/Linear1">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/doView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_below="@id/Linear1">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are u nesting too many layouts? It can become a serious performance hit. Use ConstraintLayout or avoid nesting as much as possible.

Regarding the reason why is it showing that `doView` LL is behind the `Linear1`, due to the `ScrollView` in `doView`, the content needs to be scrolled off. So it seems as if the `doView` content is behind the `Linear1` layout. When infact it is showing the scrolled off content of the `ScrollView`.

Comment: That reason I used multiple Layouts was because I'm running out of ideas. I thought if I wrap the ScrollViews inside of ```LL```, it'll force them to start below the ```LL1``` but it's still going behind the image which is making 2-3 buttons in the ```doView``` unreachable. It'll try to use ```ConstraintLayout``` maybe that'll fix it.

Comment: Well the buttons being unreachable might be some other issue. I don't think these layouts are causing it to be unreachable.. A ScrollView should be scrollable to the bottom of its child. There might be some other issue. But give a try to ConstraintLayout.